# TypeError When I Run, Argument Not Found

Tags: python

I am doing this Project where I make methods in a class that work as a ATM Vestibule but I'm getting this error:
This is my code:

```py
class bank_account:
    def __init__(self, account_number, name, balance):
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            print("Insufficient Funds")
        else:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount <= 0:
            print("Invalid Amount")
        else:
            self.balance = self.balance + amount
    def check_balance(self):
        print(self.balance)


account_holder = bank_account(input("Enter your account number, name and balance: "))
transaction = input("Please enter what transaction you would like to do: (Withdraw, Deposit) ")
amount = int(input("Enter the amount you would like to deposit or withdraw: "))

if transaction == 'withdraw' or 'Withdraw':
    account_holder.withdraw(amount)
    print(account_holder.check_balance())
elif transaction == 'deposit' or 'Deposit':
    account_holder.deposit(amount)


account_holder = bank_account(input("Enter your account number, name and balance: "))
```

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'balance'

Comment: You need to ask for the name and the balance in seperate input statements.

Comment: Unrelated: you want `a == b or a == c`, not `a == b or c`.

Comment: @chepner what do you mean?

Comment: @TheMaker `transaction == 'withdraw' or 'Withdraw'` is always true, because `'Withdraw'` is a non-empty string.

Comment: @chepner the error the OP is getting is related to the last line in his code. Have you noticed that?

Comment: Yes, which is why my comment was prefixed with "Unrelated".

Answer (score 3):

Take inputs on seperate lines and pass them when creating the object

```
class bank_account:
    def __init__(self, account_number, name, balance):
        self.account_number = account_number
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            print("Insufficient Funds")
        else:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
    def deposit(self, amount):
        if amount <= 0:
            print("Invalid Amount")
        else:
            self.balance = self.balance + amount
    def check_balance(self):
        print(self.balance)

account_number = int(input("Enter your account number: "))   # <=== Add this
name = input("Enter your Name: ")                            # <=== Add this
balance = int(input("Enter your balance: "))                 # <=== Add this
account_holder = bank_account(account_number, name, balance) # <=== Add this

transaction = input("Please enter what transaction you would like to do: (Withdraw, Deposit) ")
amount = int(input("Enter the amount you would like to deposit or withdraw: "))
if transaction == 'withdraw' or transaction == 'Withdraw':
    account_holder.withdraw(amount)
    print(account_holder.check_balance())
elif transaction == 'deposit' or transaction == 'Deposit':
    account_holder.deposit(amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with faressalem's answer. You could also just change it in one line:

```
account_holder = bank_account(input("Enter your account number: "), input("Enter your name: "), input("Enter your balance: "))
```